# React: Onclick Event new component is not returned

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React. I am trying to display new component in the content on click of menu from Navbar. But the return of component on click function doesnot work. So return  doesnot work. Here are my files. Click function "getItemsData" works but the component is not returned. I am trying to create a application with restaurant menu and it relevant content

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import "./style.css";
import Slider from "./carousel.js"
class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Header/>
     </div>
    );
  }
}
class Header extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    sections: [],
    menu: []
  };
}
componentDidMount(){
  fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/sections')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(sections => this.setState({ 'sections': sections }))

  fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/menu')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(menu => this.setState({ 'menu': menu }))
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div id="header-bar">
        <div id="header-logo">
          <img src={require('./images/1200px-Burger_King_Logo.png')}  alt="Logo" id="logo-class"></img>
        </div>
      <Slider sections={this.state.sections} menu={this.state.menu} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

carousel.js

```
import React , { Component } from 'react';
import contentCards from "./contentcards.js";


const Slider = (data) => {
    console.log(data)
   var Menuoptions = data.menu.options
   var Sectionsref = data.sections


   const getItemsData = (sectionData) => {
     sessionStorage.setItem("sectionData" , JSON.stringify(sectionData));
    return <contentCards />;

  }


return(
   <div className="sectionNavBar">
    {(()=> {
      if (Menuoptions !== undefined && Sectionsref !== undefined) {
        if (Menuoptions.length > 0 && Sectionsref.length > 0){
            let rowmenu = []
            for(let i=0; i< Menuoptions.length ; i++){
              for(let j=0; j<Sectionsref.length; j++){
                if(Menuoptions[i]._ref ===  Sectionsref[j]._id){
                  //  console.log(Menuoptions[i]._ref+ "==" +Sectionsref[j]._id)

                    let imageId  = Sectionsref[j].carouselImage.asset._ref;
                    imageId = imageId.slice(6)
                    imageId = imageId.replace("-png", ".png")
                    //console.log(Sectionsref[j])
                    rowmenu.push(<div key={j} className="listNavBar" onClick = {() => getItemsData(Sectionsref[j])}> <img src={window.location.origin + '/images/'+imageId} className= "navBar-image" /> <br/>{Sectionsref[j].name.en} </div>)

                }
              }
            }
            return rowmenu
          }

      }
    })()}
    </div>
  )

}
}export default Slider
```

contentCards.js

```
import React , { Component } from 'react';
class contentCards extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (

        <div className = "cardColumn"> Menu1 </div>
    )
  }
}
export default contentCards
```

Comment: As a side note, to improve code readability I recommend linting your code using [prettier](https://prettier.io/) and try to follow naming conventions (variables lowercase, components CamelCase)

Answer (score 0):

Custom components names [must be uppercased](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component) or React will treat them as DOM elements.

> React treats components starting with lowercase letters as DOM tags.

```
// not <contentCards />
<ContentCards />
```

Comment: I changed the component name to uppercase but it didnt worked

Comment: Try creating reproducible example as expected: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). No one can't guess why "it" doesn't work without seeing the code in action.

Comment: That's not a reproducible example, you just copied your code to stackblitz. Sorry, can't help you any further